# Matlab's radon() equivalent function in OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I want to take radon transform of an image I. In MATLAB there is a built-in function for this purpose i.e., radon(I, theta). Does anyone know any equivalent function in OpenCV? If there is no such built-in function then please tell me how it works in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV does not have a general implementation of the Radon transform. It does have an implementation of the [Hough](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) line transform which is essentially a discrete version of the Radon transform (A good explaination on the difference is [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/470/whats-the-difference-between-the-hough-and-radon-transforms)). So depending on what you need it for, that might work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually I want to convert the following code into opencv.

theta = (0:179)';
[R, xp] = radon(edgeimage, theta);

where edgeimage is the output of canny edge detection algo. Would you please suggest any equivalent Opencv function for this purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to find lines in the edge detected image?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to find lines after edge detection. Actually after googling, I came to know that OpenCV has HoughLinesP function that can be used to detect lines, so right now I am using this function and its working fine. I just have a doubt in two of its parameters i.e., "threshold" and "minLinLength". Would you please tell me the difference between threshold and minLinLength?.

Comment: The threshold is the minimum number of intersections in the Hough transform required to be called a "line". Essentially it measures the 'strength' of the line. The min line length is how long a single continuous line must be in order to be called a line.

Answer (score 0):

While OpenCV doesn't have general implementation of Radon implementation, python's `scikit-image` library has it.

```
from skimage.transform import radon
```

Here is the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_radon_transform.html).

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039831/how-to-detect-line-using-radon-transformation-using-python/76039832#76039832) for Line detection using Radon transformation.

Comment: Again, also this question is about MATLAB, not Python. It's great that you've got knowledge about OpenCV, but please don't post Python answers to MATLAB questions, unless you show how that answer can be used *within MATLAB*.

Comment: @Adriaan the OP has asked question on equivalent function in OpenCV. MATLAB is an expensive software that many people do not have access to, so people look for alternatives in free python. OpenCV has not implemented it perhaps because it is already available in scikit-image library. Many people do not know about lesser known scikit-image library.

Comment: I admit that they indeed aren't looking for a MATLAB solution, that's my bad.  However, my main point stands: if they'd be looking for a Python function, they'd have tagged the question Python and explicitly mentioned that they wanted a solution in that. So, be sure that the OP can use this within OpenCV (which in itself is difficult, as OpenCV can be called from many languages). If you want to make people aware of the Radon transform in scikit-image, please post a question yourself and answer that instead.